# Pass and Return 'Reference to a Pointer' for Binary Search Tree Insertion in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, binary-search-tree

```
/**
 * Definition for a binary tree node.
 * struct TreeNode {
 *     int val;
 *     TreeNode *left;
 *     TreeNode *right;
 *     TreeNode() : val(0), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x) : val(x), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {}
 *     TreeNode(int x, TreeNode *left, TreeNode *right) : val(x), left(left), right(right) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    TreeNode* insertIntoBST(TreeNode* root, int val) {
        TreeNode*& node = find(root, val);
        node = new TreeNode(val);
        return root;
    }
    TreeNode*& find(TreeNode*& root, int& val) {
        if (root == nullptr) return root;
        else if (root->val > val) return find(root->left, val);
        else return find(root->right, val);
    }
};
```

I am learning C++ and read this code on a lecture slide. The code is about the insertion of a new node into a binary search tree. The idea is to find the target location and then insert a new node to the location. I can understand the reason for the 'find' function returning a 'reference to pointer' type. I think it is because we need to modify the address of the target location after the 'find' function returns. However, I don't know why we need to use the 'reference to pointer' type also when we pass the root node into the 'find' function. If I change TreeNode*& find(TreeNode*& root, int& val) to TreeNode*& find(TreeNode* root, int& val), the program will return the original tree without the target insertion. Can anyone help with this question? Thank you in advance!

Comment: The find function doesn't need the reference, but the insert function seems to need it. Probably so that `node = new TreeNode(val);` can update some part of the tree. I would deem this as "to cute", as it is not obvious at all how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change `find` to `TreeNode*& find(TreeNode* root, int& val)` then look at the first line of the function:

```
    if (root == nullptr) return root;
```

This would return a reference to a local variable. Changing it in `insertIntoBST` is undefined behavior and will not change the `root` variable inside `insertIntoBST`.

Go through the code step by step when inserting the first value into an empty tree:

```
NodeTree *tree = nullptr;
tree = insertIntoBST(tree, 42);
```

---

The `insertIntoBST` function could use the same trick as find and modify the root in place:

```
void insertIntoBST(TreeNode*& root, int val) {
    TreeNode*& node = find(root, val);
    node = new TreeNode(val);
}

NodeTree *tree = nullptr;
insertIntoBST(tree, 42);
insertIntoBST(tree, 23);
insertIntoBST(tree, 666);
```

or even shorter:

```
void insertIntoBST(TreeNode*& root, int val) {
    find(root, val) = new TreeNode(val);
}
```